# AppEngine: Unable to update app: Failed to compile jsp files

Tags: google-app-engine

I just update my AppEngine SDK from 1.7.0 to 1.7.5 because of the problem related to adding document in Full Text Search API.

But now, I can not upload the application.

Here are the errors:

```
Deploying to Google' has encountered a problem
Unable to update app: Failed to compile jsp files.
```

In the log file:

```
Unable to update:
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException: Failed to compile jsp files.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.compileJsps(Application.java:756)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.createStagingDirectory(Application.java:592)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:370)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:53)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:433)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you need to have the JDK pointing in your build path of eclipse.

[image: Build Path]

[image: JDK Location]

**Click on Installed JREs and point it upto your JDK installed location.**

[image: Installed JDK Path]

If that even didn't work go to **eclipse.ini** file in your eclipse directory. Add the following argument.

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk_1.6.30\bin\javaw.exe
```

Then restart your eclipse and things will start working.

Comment: still encountered d problem, since im using linux I added '-vm
/opt/jdk1.6.0_43/bin/java' but didn't work

Comment: Line must be separated in -vm and /opt/jdk/bin/javaw like I have done. It should be **javaw** not **java**

Comment: i don't see javaw file in linux. from this references it says java http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini.

Comment: Then hopefully it should work, because these are the maximum changes we can do to run appengine sdk 1.7.4 and 1.7.5 with local and during deployment to appspot.

Comment: No problem in local, problem occured during deployment. huh :-(

Comment: Try reinstalling your JDK but without JRE. And then test, this also I have found somewhere as many people like us were facing the same problem. My problem was solved with Windows-8 by changing the build path to JDK in eclipse project properties and adding the **vm** argrument in eclipse.ini file.

Comment: @JRGalia its a pleasure to help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

Run the app on your local development server, you will discover the JSP files have errors that you need to sort out before compiling.